# Funnelweb TypeError on import

Tags: plone, plone-funnelweb

I have tried import some pages doing like this:

```
bin/funnelweb --crawler:url=http://wiki.scandiatransplant.org --crawler:max=50 --ploneupload=http://admin:localhost:8080/Plone
```

But I get this error message:

```
Usage: funnelweb [options]

funnelweb: error: ambiguous option: --ploneupload (--ploneupload:debug, --ploneupload:target?)
```

If instead I do this: 
 (But if this worked, where will the imported pages be placed?)

```
bin/funnelweb --crawler:url=http://wiki.scandiatransplant.org --crawler:max=150
```

It works, as if it is importing, but at the end I get the traceback seen below. At the bottom it says: `TypeError: replace() takes exactly 7 arguments (6 given)`

Is this the creators mistake, or is it me giving insufficient arguments?
I used this site for the tutorial: http://plone.org/products/funnelweb

```
INFO:typeguess:Document, text/html: 144
INFO:typeguess:Image, image/jpeg: 1
INFO:typeguess:Link, : 1
INFO:template1:extracted 0/144/151
INFO:template2:extracted 0/144/151
INFO:template3:extracted 0/144/151
INFO:template4:extracted 0/144/151
INFO:sitemapper:moved 0/151 from 0 sitemaps
INFO:indexguess:2 folders added. 0 defaultpages set, 149 items sorted
INFO:titleguess:0 folders added. 0 defaultpages set, 149 items sorted
INFO:titleguess:titles=0/148 (id=0,backlinks=0,parent=0)
INFO:attachmentguess:moved 0/154
INFO:urltidy:titles=0, normed=147, total=154
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/funnelweb", line 116, in <module>
    mr.migrator.runner.runner({},"funnelweb.remote")
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/mr.migrator-1.0.1-py2.7.egg/mr/migrator/runner/__init__.py", line 132, in runner
    transmogrifier(pipelineid, **overrides)
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.transmogrifier-1.3-py2.7.egg/collective/transmogrifier/transmogrifier.py", line 62, in __call__
    for item in pipeline:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.ploneremote-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/ploneremote/remoteprune.py", line 116, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.ploneremote-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/ploneremote/remoteredirector.py", line 25, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.ploneremote-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/ploneremote/remoteworkflowupdater.py", line 41, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.transmogrifier-1.3-py2.7.egg/collective/transmogrifier/sections/inserter.py", line 19, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.ploneremote-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/ploneremote/remotenavigationexcluder.py", line 32, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.ploneremote-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/ploneremote/remoteschemaupdater.py", line 42, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.ploneremote-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/ploneremote/remoteconstructor.py", line 53, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.siteanalyser-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/siteanalyser/treeserializer.py", line 51, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.transmogrifier-1.3-py2.7.egg/collective/transmogrifier/sections/inserter.py", line 19, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.siteanalyser-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/siteanalyser/treeserializer.py", line 51, in __iter__
    for item in self.previous:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.siteanalyser-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/siteanalyser/urltidy.py", line 83, in __iter__
    for item in self.relinker:
  File "/home/magiq/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.siteanalyser-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/siteanalyser/relinker.py", line 155, in __iter__
    item['remoteUrl'] = "./" + replace(link, item, changes, counter, self.missing, bad)
TypeError: replace() takes exactly 7 arguments (6 given)
```

Comment: Please do try and think of better question titles :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have run into a bug, yes. I've filed this as an issue in the [`transmogrify.siteanalyser` issue tracker](https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.siteanalyser/issues), see [issue #3](https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.siteanalyser/issues/3).

The `replace()` method was [given an extra parameter](https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.siteanalyser/commit/e7679bfabdd070ce012f82f1f0ab88f471590146) but the call on line 155 was never updated to provide that extra parameter.

You should be able to fix this yourself by editing the file [`Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.siteanalyser-1.3-py2.7.egg/transmogrify/siteanalyser/relinker.py`](https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.siteanalyser/blob/a6e79130a9dc39a5e66ad79e86594ae3e2f24694/transmogrify/siteanalyser/relinker.py#L155) and change line 155 from:

```
item['remoteUrl'] = "./" + replace(link, item, changes, counter, self.missing, bad)
```

to

```
item['remoteUrl'] = "./" + replace(link, item, changes, counter, self.missing, bad, self.broken_link_normalise)
```